# How to copy git repository including only one subfolder?

Tags: git

Is there a way to create a new git repository from an existing one, the new repository should include only files located in the specified subfolder and only commits that affects these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter foodir -- --all
```

(Example taken from the [git documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch))

Comment: yes, that's almost it. but how can I keep my project root folder the same? I want all my files have their location unchanged

Comment: To keep the location unchanged within the repository, you would probably use the --tree-filter parameter instead of the --subdirectory-filter, and pass a shell command that would delete everything except the directory you want to keep.